# Django HTML image not found but path is correct

Tags: python, django, django-views

So i am creating a list with images but the image is not showing. This is my model:

```
class Hongos(models.Model):

def image_upload(self,filename):
    return 'imagenes_hongos/'+str(self.uploader.user)+'/'+str(filename)

nombre = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
prob = models.FloatField(null=False)
uploader = models.ForeignKey(HongOSUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload)
```

This is my view:

```
 <ul class="list-group shadow">
                <!-- list group item-->
                {%for hongo in hongos%}
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <!-- Custom content-->
                    <div class="media align-items-lg-center flex-column flex-lg-row p-3">
                        <div class="media-body order-2 order-lg-1">
                            <h5 class="mt-0 font-weight-bold mb-2">{{hongo.nombre}}</h5>
                            <!-- <p class="font-italic text-muted mb-0 small"></p> -->
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mt-1">
                                <h6 class="font-weight-bold my-2">{{hongo.prob}}</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div><img src='/hongOS_project/{{hongo.imagen}}' alt='{{hongo.nombre}}' width="200"
                            class="ml-lg-5 order-1 order-lg-2">
                    </div> <!-- End -->
                </li> <!-- End -->
                {%endfor%}
            </ul> <!-- End -->
```

And this is my directory:

[Dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGdkG.png)

I get this errors:

```
Not Found: /hongOS_project/imagenes_hongos/pableras/amanita.jpg
Not Found: /hongOS_project/imagenes_hongos/pableras/amanita_LNFLqKi.jpg
[20/Jul/2022 10:10:50] "GET /hongOS_project/imagenes_hongos/pableras/amanita_LNFLqKi.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2900    
[20/Jul/2022 10:10:50] "GET /hongOS_project/imagenes_hongos/pableras/amanita.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2876
```

I think it should work since the path is correct, but it is not working.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as images.

Comment: please provide a code, not an image

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Higher chances of getting answers come after reading [ask].

In particular, code and data are required to be posted as [text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). Don't hesitate to take a quick [tour]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have configured the settings.py of your project to handle media assets. The best way to handle media files uploading and rendering in Django templates is to use proper conventions defined in Django documentation.

To answer the question, make sure you have added/done the followings:

Settings.py file

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Your mail urls.py file should also have this code...

```
urlpatterns = [
# urls/path
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In your models.py file, configure your images field like this...

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'add_folder_name_of_your_choice/', null=True)
```

Then in your template load your images using this way...

```
 <ul class="list-group shadow">
            <!-- list group item-->
            {%for hongo in hongos%}
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <!-- Custom content-->
                <div class="media align-items-lg-center flex-column flex-lg-row p-3">
                    <div class="media-body order-2 order-lg-1">
                        <h5 class="mt-0 font-weight-bold mb-2">{{hongo.nombre}}</h5>
                        <!-- <p class="font-italic text-muted mb-0 small"></p> -->
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mt-1">
                            <h6 class="font-weight-bold my-2">{{hongo.prob}}</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div><img src='{{hongo.imagen.url}}' alt='{{hongo.nombre}}' width="200"
                        class="ml-lg-5 order-1 order-lg-2">
                </div> <!-- End -->
            </li> <!-- End -->
            {%endfor%}
        </ul> <!-- End -->
```